# How do I scp a file to a Unix host so that a file polling service won't see it before the copy is complete?

Tags: unix, scp

I am trying to transfer a file to a remote Unix server using scp. On that server, there is a service which polls the target directory to detect incoming files for processing. I would like to ensure that the polling service does not pick up new files before the copy is complete. Is there a way of doing that?

My file transfer process is a simple scp command embedded in a larger Java program. Ideally, a solution which did *not* involve changing the Jana would be best (for reasons involving change control processes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can scp the file to a different (/tmp) directory and move the
  file via ssh after transfer is complete. The different directory needs to be on the same partition as the final destination directory otherwise there will be a copy operation and you'll face a similar problem. Another service on the destination machine can do this move operation.
- You can copy the file as hidden (prefix the filename with `.`) and copy, then move
- If you can modify the polling service, you can check active scp processes and ignore files matching scp arguments.
- You can check for open files with `lsof +d $directory` and ignore them in the polling server

Comment: prefixing the filename with . may or may not hide it from the file polling service.

Comment: Copying to a different directory and moving after transfer is complete is a good solution, but requires that the alternate location be on the same partition as the final destination.  That should be noted in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest copying the file using [`rsync`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rsync&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) instead of `scp`.  `rsync` already copies new files to temporary filenames, and has many other useful features for file synchronization as well.

```
$ rsync -a source/path/ remotehost:/target/path/
```

Of course, you can also copy file-by-file if that's your preference.

If `rsync`'s temporary filenames are sufficient to avoid being picked up by your polling service, then you could simply replace your `scp` command with a shell script that acts as a wrapper for `rsync`, eliminating the need to change your Java program.

You would need to know the precise format that your Java program uses to call the `scp` command, to make sure that the options you feed to `rsync` do what you expect.

You would also need to figure out how your Java program calls `scp`.  If it does so by full pathname (i.e. `/usr/bin/scp`), then this solution might put other things at risk on your system that depend on scp (like you, for example, expecting scp to behave as it usually does instead of as a wrapper).  Changing a package-installed binary like `/usr/bin/scp` may also "break" your package registration, making it difficult to install future security updates because a binary has changed to a shell script.  And of course, there might be security implications to any change you make.

All in all, I suspect you're better off changing your Java program to make it do precisely what you want, even if that is to launch a shell script to handle aspects of automation that you want to be able to change in the future without modifying your Java.

Good luck!